# Span around last two letters of word with jquery?

Tags: jquery, target

I've spotted lots of examples of targeting specific works in a header or div using jQuery, but what I'm after is slightly different.

I'm using Jigoshop for an e-commerce site and would like to make the decimal places of the price of the products smaller than the rest of the numbers.

Currently, Jigoshop exports out the prices like so:

```
<div class="price">£300.00</div>
```

But ideally, I'd like this:

```
<div class="price">£300.<span class="decimals">00</span></div>
```

The full stop/decimal place can always be used as a separator if that helps.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$(".price").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace( /(\.\d+)$/, '<span class="decimals">$1</span>')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kF7LK/)

Comment: Beautiful! Works a treat. Thank you.

Comment: Oops… I've realised that ideally I'd like to include the decimal place in the span too. Is this possible?

Comment: Amazing thank you. One last thing, is there a way I can make this also target a price within a div that's been set to display:none (at first)?

Comment: @user3004305 sorry it should target all elements with class price

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be

```
$( ".price" ).html( function( index, oldHtml ){
    return oldHtml.replace( /(\d\d)$/, "<span class='decimals'>$1</span>" );
});
```

EDIT: fixed so that it works for multiple prices. So it's the same as the top answer, with a slightly different RegExp (probably faster, but I doubt it would make much of a difference)

Comment: oh yes... gosh confusing when people change the code when i am trying to change it too :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for editing. By the way, you made the same "mistake" like me in assuming there was only one `.price`. You might want to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
var price = $('.price').text();
price = price.split('.');
$('.price').html(price[0] + '.<span class="decimals">' + price[1] + '</span>');
```

But be aware that modifying the DOM via JS to archive some styling is a somewhat bad practice!

If you have multiple prices:

```
$('.price').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).text();
    price = price.split('.');
    $(this).html(price[0] + '.<span class="decimals">' + price[1] + '</span>');
}
```

Comment: I think he's got multiple prices on the page. Your advice is spot-on tho

Comment: Thanks David, I added a snippet for that case now.

Answer (score 1):

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BK8NS/)

```
$('div.price').html(function (_, old_html) {
    return old_html.substr(0, old_html.indexOf('.')) + '<span class="decimals">' + old_html.substr(old_html.indexOf('.')) + '</span>';
});
```

---

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is **really bad** practice. However, here's how you'd do that.

```
$('.price').each(function () {
    var p = $(this);
    var t = p.text().split('.');
    var s = $('<span></span>');
    s.attr('class', 'decimals');
    s.text(t[1])
    p.text("");
    p.text(t[0] + ".");
    p.append(s);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL7Dy/).

Comment: Why is this 'really bad' practice?

Comment: generating the DOM structure is something that should be done by who outputs it and not the client.